# CSS transform 3d cube offsets

Tags: html, css, 3d

I am trying to use CSS 3D transforms to display cubes and cuboids which will contain cross-sections.
I am targeting Chrome, Firefox and MSIE 11. I have found that to maintain MSIE 11 compatibility, I need to avoid using transform-type: preserve-3d, as this is not supported by Microsoft, so I need to apply all parent and child transforms to each cube face.

For a cube, I can rotate each side to align them correctly, but for a cuboid, the ends are offset - why is this, and how can I fix it?

This screenshot illustrates the problem:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="test test1">
    <h1>1.</h1>
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="side front">1</div>
        <div class="side back">6</div>
        <div class="side right">4</div>
        <div class="side left">3</div>
        <div class="side top">5</div>
        <div class="side bottom">2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test test2">
    <h1>2.</h1>
    <div class="cube cuboid">
        <div class="side front">1</div>
        <div class="side back">6</div>
        <div class="side right">4</div>
        <div class="side left">3</div>
        <div class="side top">5</div>
        <div class="side bottom">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
    div.test {
        height: 200px;
    }

    /* basic cube */
    .cube {
        font-size: 4em;
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        /* MSIE11 does not support preserve-3d.
          for MSIE all transforms must be applied to all elements */
    }

    .side {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
    /* for MSIE11 compatibility, avoid using a transform on the parent, combine all parent+child transforms, transform-style: preserve3d is not supported */
    .front {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) translateZ(50px);
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .top {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .right {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
    }
    .left {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .bottom {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
    }
    .back {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(-148deg) translateZ(50px);
    }

    /* cuboid - 100 x 100 x 200 */
    .cuboid .front {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .cuboid .top {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .cuboid .right {
        transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(122deg) translateZ(150px);
    }
    .cuboid .back {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .cuboid .bottom {
        width: 200px;
    }
```

Here is a JSFiddle of this code: https://jsfiddle.net/6h7mmtgn/

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I am still interested in an answer for this, if anyone has any useful suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

```
.cuboid .left,
.cuboid .right {
     margin-top: 16px;
     margin-left: 7px;
}
```

Demonstration below:

```css
div.test {
    xwidth: 100%;
    xperspective: 750px;
    height: 200px;
}
/* basic cube */
 .cube {
    font-size: 4em;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    /* MSIE11 does not support preserve-3d.
     for MSIE all transforms must be applied to all elements */
}
.side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
/* for MSIE11 compatibility, avoid using a transform on the parent, combine all parent+child transforms, transform-style: preserve3d is not supported */
 .front {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) translateZ(50px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.top {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.right {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.left {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.back {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(-148deg) translateZ(50px);
}
/* cuboid - 100 x 100 x 200 */
 .cuboid .front {
    width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .top {
    width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .right {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(122deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.cuboid .back {
    width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .bottom {
    width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .left, .cuboid .right {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test test1">
    <h1>1.</h1>
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="side front">1</div>
        <div class="side back">6</div>
        <div class="side right">4</div>
        <div class="side left">3</div>
        <div class="side top">5</div>
        <div class="side bottom">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test test2">
    <h1>2.</h1>
    <div class="cube cuboid">
        <div class="side front">1</div>
        <div class="side back">6</div>
        <div class="side right">4</div>
        <div class="side left">3</div>
        <div class="side top">5</div>
        <div class="side bottom">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h7mmtgn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This fixes the display for these particular cuboid dimensions, but the margin values seem a bit arbitrary. Why do these margin values need to be added, and what happens if I change my cuboid dimensions?

Comment: I am glad that helps. To my knowledge the shifting happens because of the z axis transformation.  3D (x,y,z) axis. When you translate ie(translateZ) you are moving the object into z axis. If you change the cuboid dimensions you'll have to increase the margin value too. Can accept it as answer? Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but it's not quite the full answer I was hoping for. It fixes the symptoms of the display bug, but not the cause of it. In the real world, my cuboids will have dimensions set dynamically by javascript, so if I have to add extra margins, I need to be able to calculate them, rather than arrive at them experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

I think its about the transform-origin. Try to set explicit origins on your sides like:

```
transform-origin: 51px 51px;
```