# Why does a margin appears when the div size is changed by translate3d?

Tags: css, css-transforms

When I change the div size, an indent appears between the blocks.

```
<div class="test2">test2
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Help me how to remove it?

```css
.container {
    perspective: 600px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.test2 {
    /* more to fiddle */
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
}
.test3 {
    /* more to fiddle */
    transform: translate3d(0,-34px,0) rotate3d(1,0,0,-45deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="test1">test1</div>
    <div class="test2">test2</div>
    <div class="test3">test3</div>
</div>
```

Without margin: [image]

With margin: [image]

https://jsfiddle.net/gipahs/ved2q3vd/9/

P.S. I see [CSS transform 3d cube offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859726/css-transform-3d-cube-offsets), but I think that's different problem.

Comment: which size you mean ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The OP means when adding content to .test2 class container.

Comment: I got the fix for when extra items are added for the bottom two divs but the top div doesn't align then which has no transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have is not margin but a logical space added due to the transfomation you are using. You may notice that you added a **translation** to fix this issue at the first try.

Imagine you have a closed window and when you open both sides you will be able to see space between both side which is logical as you applied a rotation to both sides :

[image]

So the rotation of your div will create the same effect :

[image]

So to fix it you can apply a translation like you did with the first one but you will notice that both side won't have the same width because both div doesn't have the same **height** and a rotation with same angle will make width **different** (this is perspective, a close object look bigger that a far one)

[image]

So to fix this you have to also add translation on the Z-axis to make the second div more closer and have this :

[image]

Full code :

```css
.container
{
    perspective: 600px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.test1
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
}

.test2
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;

}

.test3
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    
    transform: translate3d(0,-57px,57px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-45deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="test1">test1</div>
            <div class="test2">test2
              <p>hello</p>
              <p>hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="test3">test3</div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But that doesn't fix the width difference.

Comment: @Highdef yes as it's not an issue ... this is a logic effect of the transformation used with two different width ... i think we need to understand that what's happening is not an issue but the normal behavior

Comment: But, I actually got the fix for the bottom two divs to maintain their view with no additonal transformation whatsoever, but the top div is a seperate issue.

Comment: @Highdef *got the fix*, am not sure a fix for what :) but show me so i can see

Comment: @TemaniAfif  This is the best example with windows that I have ever seen. Thank you so much. Now I understand where I go next

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution (partial) to achieve the fixed view and no seperation whatsoever between the rotated divs.

- We're making use of `transform-origin:center bottom; for the test2` and `transform-origin: center top; for test3`. This ensures that those two common edges stay at the **fixed width of 50%**.
- The **issue with this approach** is if we try to align the **test1** which is the topmost div with no rotating or transformation whatsoever, we need to **manually adjust its width and margin** to make it stick to the top of test2.

**Without test1:**

```css
.container
{
   perspective:600px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.test2
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;

}

.test3
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,-45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="test2">test2
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="test3">test3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**With test1: (without adjustments)**

```css
.container
{
   perspective:600px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.test1
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
}

.test2
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;

}

.test3
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,-45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="test1">test1</div>
    <div class="test2">test2
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="test3">test3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: as you can see you changed the origin of rotation and thus you made the rotation on another axis which is the one between both of them :) .. so it's not a fix but another way to rotate with its own logic and you see that you will have the same *issue*(which is also logic) with the first div

Comment: @TemaniAfif Like I said, one is going to suffer for the others but it fixes the specific problem that OP was facing adjusting the two rotated divs.

Comment: that's why i said there is no issue but we simply need to understand the logic :) i know you got it ... but i think the OP is not understanding this

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, well I hope these 2 solutions might make him understand :)

Comment: i added more details to my answer and another idea on how to keep both divs stay close ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif And adding another item will mess the layout again. http://prntscr.com/hruibv So readjustments after every other item is added.

Comment: yes for sure, but i think it's clear since we are using fixed value in all the transformation,  there is no generic solution .. it's like building a castle of cards, you change one size of one card and all the castle fall :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161910/discussion-between-highdef-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @Highdef Thank you for your help and sample code. I to do it.