# How to achieve the effect shown below using CSS transform:rotateY() or by any other way possible....Thanks

Tags: css, transform

This is a specific style in which the div are placed in. The way they are positioned are probably achieved by skewing and rotating across multiple axes. I have tried hard but haven't been able to exactly replicate the effect below.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963793/8620333